# Angular set routing parent and children

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-routing

I'm very new to Angular and I really need help on routing. This is my folder structure:

[image]

There are two different layouts, one is a layout for login page, and one is the main layout like the usual admin page which has sidebar, toolbar, etc.

After login, I expected it to load the dashboard page with main layout, but instead it only show the layout and not the dashboard.

**app-routing.module.ts**

```
const accountModule = () => import('./features/account/account.module').then(x => x.AccountModule);
const mainModule = () => import('./features/main/main.module').then(x => x.MainModule);

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', loadChildren: mainModule, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
  { path: 'account', loadChildren: accountModule },

  // otherwise redirect to home
  { path: '**', redirectTo: '' }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
```

**account-routing.module.ts**

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '', component: LayoutComponent,
    children: [
        { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
    ]
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
```

**main-routing.module.ts**

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '', component: LayoutComponent,
    children: [
        { path: 'dashboard', component: DashboardComponent },
        { path: 'client', component: ClientComponent },
    ]
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
```

How can I modify the route so that when I access http://localhost:4200 it will show dashboard page with main layout instead of just the layout? Or if it's not possible, redirect it to http://localhost:4200/dashboard? Please help.

Comment: add  `{ path: '', redirectTo: 'dashboard', pathMatch: 'full' },`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your main-routing.module.ts
Use match path full with empty string an redirect you your desired path.

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '', component: LayoutComponent,
    children: [
        { path: 'dashboard', component: DashboardComponent },
        { path: 'client', component: ClientComponent },
    ]
  },
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'dashboard', pathMatch: 'full' },

];
```

EDIT: Corrected order

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'dashboard', pathMatch: 'full' },
  {
    path: '', component: LayoutComponent,
    children: [
        { path: 'dashboard', component: DashboardComponent },
        { path: 'client', component: ClientComponent },
    ]
  },
];
```

Comment: It didn't work this way, but It's working if it is added at first line. Is it supposed to be added first before adding the route with children?

Comment: That would work yes. Think of the router to look for matches from top to bottom. So the more vague routes you would put lower. Maybe this case it needs to be higher only due to its an empty string. Added an edit to the answer